# Highlighting a cell that contains a value based on other cells value

Tags: arrays, excel, formula

[click for image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WiTIM.png)

Hello, Im looking for a formula or conditional formatting that would highlight a order number that i put in a certain column based on the same order number in a different column that contains a negative on-hand qty. Ill try and explain this the best i can (see link for pic)

So in column V from row 3 and below i put a order number, its position in this column is completely random and has no relation to the rest of the worksheet other than its value. when i put the order number in column T through Z it highlights that order in column D, depending on which column i put the order number in determines the color but really that's irrelevant to my question. My question is when i put a order number in Column V (shipping tomorrow) i would like it to highlight the order number in V red if the available qty in column Q is negative.

So for example the first order in row 3 is G38762-00, if i were to put that in column V it would highlight that order in column D yellow, but seeing that the available qty for that order in column Q is -10 i would like that order number in Column V to turn red showing me that i don't have it to ship! any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: use a combination of index match in your conditional formatting

Comment: ok i did some reading on index match but i still cant wrap my brain around how to make it turn the text red when the value is less than 0.

Answer (score 0):

In coditional formatting use the following formula on Cell V3:

`=INDEX($P$3:$Q$1000,MATCH(V3,$P$3:$P$1000,0),2)<0`

Here I assume that your order numbers are in column P with appropriate quantities in column Q.